# Refreshing an activity with spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have an activity with a spinner and a listView. Depending on the item selected on spinner, the list view displays different data.
When i refresh im calling the method populate to make populate the activity again. The problem is that spinner will assume that im clicking on the same item that was previously selected, therefore wont enter onSelectListener after refresh

public void populate(int idEnfermaria) {

```
  final String idS = String.valueOf(idEnfermaria);
    spinnerNursery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(NurseryActivity.this, "Carregando...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (position == 0) {
                tvInfo.setText("Lista de utentes da enfermaria " + idS);
                NetworkManager.getInstance().getUtentesEnfermaria(idS, new NetworkManager.ListaUtentesListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void recieveResponse(final List<Utente> listaUtentes, Exception erro) {
                        swipeRefreshNursery.setRefreshing(false);
                        if (listaUtentes != null) {
                            UtenteAdapter adapterUtentes = new UtenteAdapter(NurseryActivity.this, listaUtentes);
                            listViewUtentesOrProcs.setAdapter(adapterUtentes);
                            listViewUtentesOrProcs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                                    Utente utente = listaUtentes.get(position);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(NurseryActivity.this, PatientActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra(Controlador.VIEW_PATIENT, utente);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(NurseryActivity.this, "Erro inesperado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("ERRO: " + erro.toString());
                        }
                    }//fim do recieve response
                });//final do listener de utentes
            }
            else if(position == 1){
                tvInfo.setText("Lista de procedimentos da enfermaria " + idS);
                NetworkManager.getInstance().getProcedimentosPorEnfermaria(idS, new NetworkManager.ListaProcedimentosListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void recieveResponse(final List<Procedimento> listaProcedimentos, Exception erro) {
                        swipeRefreshNursery.setRefreshing(false);
                        if (listaProcedimentos != null) {
                            final List<Procedimento> lista = Controlador.ordenarKardexUtente(listaProcedimentos);
                            ProcedimentoAdapter adapterProcs = new ProcedimentoAdapter(NurseryActivity.this, lista);
                            listViewUtentesOrProcs.setAdapter(adapterProcs);
                            listViewUtentesOrProcs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                                    Procedimento procedimento = lista.get(position);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(NurseryActivity.this, ProcedureActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra(Controlador.VIEW_PROC, procedimento);
                                    intent.putExtra(Controlador.ACTIVITY, Controlador.ACTIVITY_NURSERY);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(NurseryActivity.this, "Erro inesperado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            System.out.println("ERRO: " + erro.getMessage());
                        }
                    }//fim do recieve response
                });//final do listener de servicos
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });//fim do listener do spinnerNursery

    listViewUtentesOrProcs.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int i1, int i2) {
            if (firstVisibleItem == 0) {
                swipeRefreshNursery.setEnabled(true);
            } else swipeRefreshNursery.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Im trying to make it so when i swipe down, to refresh the activity, it will enter populate and reload all data (enter onItemSelected, etc).

I've tried to put spinner.setSelection(0) in refresh, but it only works if the item's index that i had previously selected was different than 0.
Thanks